# Parsing Fast ESP queries to SOLR query syntax

Tags: performance, search, solr, search-engine, fast-esp

I have a website that had fast esp as a search engine,  now migrating to solr. I have some queries I extracted from Fast esp logs,  I would like to parse those queries to a suitable format to search on SOLR,  any known tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort, I found out there is no tool for now that can parse FAST ESP queries to Solr queries (syntax wise).

I had to develop my own.

Heard that Solr developers team are trying to develop a tool that will do just that.
Meanwhile, you will have to wait, or develop your own tool.

After testing the one I developed - I will publish it for public use.